# gem install anything returns (Errno::EPERM) on debian jessie (8.3)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, debian

Just created a fresh DigitalOcean server using Debian 8.3 (Jessie) 64-bit and trying to install Resque

Doing the normal ruby install (sudo gem install) is returning

`user@server:~$ sudo gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - sendto(2) for "2001:4860:4860::8844" port 53`

So tried to do rbenv (to be able to use gem install without sudo) via
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-14-04

After the long process ... now finally able to run without sudo still yields

`user@server:~$ gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - sendto(2) for "2001:4860:4860::8844" port 53`

Not really sure what do to next ... not really a Ruby guy, just trying to install resque

Comment: I haven't seen this particular error before, but I don't think it's a Ruby issue. It sounds like a networking problem. sendto(2) is a system call for sending a message to a socket. Port 53 is used for DNS. This leads me to believe that RubyGems is not able to resolve the rubygems.org server for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah. 53 is DNS. guessing that gem cannot resolve the location from where you are pulling the gem. **What happens if you try to hit rubygems directly?**

http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/suggestions/44-ipv6

**Do you have an ip v4 on the machine?**

Answer (score 0):

It was the firewall (ufw + iptables)

- Need to change `/etc/default/ufw` from `IPV6=no` to `IPV6=yes`
- `sudo ufw allow 53`
- `sudo ufw disable`
- `sudo ufw enable`